# После логина в админку редирект на /accounts/profile/

Tags: python, django

Доброго дня, приключилась вот какая проблемка: при логине в админку на джанго-сайте вместо того, что бы после удачного логина перекидывать в /admin(адрес админки), перекидывает на "/accounts/profile/" (стандартный редирект после логина) - т.о. получаем 404 ошибку. Другими словами, перестал подхватываться url для переадресации после удачного логина(?next=value). Сайт работает под Django 1.3, Python 2.7.1+, стоит grappelly 2.1. Есть сомнения, что может это старая граппелли путает все концы? Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тоже когда-то был такой баг, вроде обновил grappelli и его не стало. Сейчас Django 1.3, Python 2.6, grappelly 2.3.2, бага нет.

Comment: Вот и у меня те же подозрения. Думаю, что в старой граппелли юзаются параметры, которые уже не актуальны для последних версий джанги. Сейчас займусь обновлением...

Comment: Обновил граппелли - и проблема исчезла, мы были правы :)